# 3d animation - WPF or XNA

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, 3d, xna

I would like to make a 3d animation of a few dozens of primitives

[image]

I read the initial position of each atom and with other parameters I need to draw an animation that describe the ordering. I need to view then of all angles, manipulate the color and alpha channel.

All in all, it narrows to **WPF 3D or XNA**.

I would choose WPF, because I know it and it is a way much easier to add a TextBox to the app.
Yet I am afraid that WPF won't handle the animation or it would be problematic if I need to add some extra bits.

Which one is better for it? Can you point me to some examples how to manage datastructres and draw the animation? (I am new to 3d animations)

EDIT:
If anyone is interested in here the code and the app http://alloysvisualisation.codeplex.com/ I use Model3DGroup to build a mode from GeometryModel3D. As a result, performance is pretty good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use both WPF and XNA for 3D rendering in the projects I'm currently working on. The XNA stuff is used from within a WPF application, so there is no problem using those two combined either.

I would use WPF for the 3D rendering if you have a simple scene since I like the abstraction it gives you. You simply add objects to the scene, set up some cameras and lights and the rest is handled for you. We use WPF for a visual editor containing up to ~500 cylinders without any performance problems. The one performance issue we have had is that it takes a long time to add/remove objects from the scene. So WPF is not a good fit if that is something you need to do a lot of.

However, if you have more complex needs or if the application is performance critical I would go with XNA to get closer to the metal. It gives you a more "classic", OpenGL like approach to rendering.

To summarize:

**WPF:**

- Simple to use
- Nice abstraction
- Ok performance overall
- Poor performance when adding/removing objects

**XNA:**

- Close to the metal
- Good performance
- Feels more like OpenGL if you are used to that
- Works with both WinForms and WPF

A resource that we have used for the WPF side of things is [Charles Petzold's writings](http://www.charlespetzold.com/3D/) on the subject. We currently use stuff from his library. It got us started quickly, but we've had some issues, so I would recommend some caution. However, the stuff on his site is worth looking at.

Comment: Well, objects can be added and removed, but perhaps 10-20 objects are added/removed. Adding/removing hundreds of items takes longer than we'd like, so opening the scene is not fast.

Answer (score 3):

XNA + WPF is the solution. This article will guide you through the process: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38301/XNA-integration-inside-WPF

Definetely XNA is faster and more convenient for extensive 3D work. WPF is fine for 3D, but XNA is easier to debug and offers several nice features, such as additive alpha blending and a Camera object. Also, you can find good libraries to support your work.

If you are not sure, then you should without doubt use an XNA object to draw the graphics. WPF will provide you with buttons and text, which, in turn, are a pain in XNA.

Answer (score 2):

Xna will offer easier debugging of the 3d aspects.

You could follow the winforms example to host xna in a windows forms form and then all the familiar controls like drop downs and buttons will work fine and interact with xna.

Comment: Is there a good example how to structure the app to draw n objects with camera etc.?